# How to directly click/tap text link inside message block by Appium automated tool

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I want to click the url to redirect to the website, but in the message app, every message has its own block, like the screenshot following, every click can only be binded to the block, not the message, when I cannot click accurately to the text url, the page cannot jump to the website, so  what can be done to bind click to the url text. Does anyone have any suggestions? thank you

[image: image here]